Pydantic and Pydantic settings parsing a list
We are trying to use pydantic and pydantic settings in our django app
We have an environment setting such as
ENV_VAR = A,B,C,
if I use
env_var: list[str] = []
I get a pydantic parsing error
if I use
env_var: str = []
it parses this but further code treats it as a str
ie
for var in ENV_VAR:
print (var)
fails
I tried a custom validator to split the env var but this made no difference
Thanks for any help
